# open file with non-default colorscheme using vim

Tags: vim

I used to know an option to add when using vim which would open the editor using the specified color. I don't want to permanently change the color system-wide, but rather use an alias to open a file in a different scheme.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `+` or `-c`

`:h startup`:

```
+command, -c command
             Execute command after reading the first file.  Up to 10
             instances allowed.  "+foo" and -c "foo" are equivalent.
```

---

```
$ vim +'colo blue' ~/.bashrc
$ vim -c 'colo blue' ~/.bashrc
```

---

`~/.bashrc` alias:

```
alias vimcolor="vim -c 'colo blue' $@"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).